# How to resolve 404/403 issues when hosting react app on IIS with SSL enabled?

Tags: reactjs, iis, iis-8

I need to deploy a react app to the IIS (version 8.5) with SSL certificate enabled. To make my issue more clear I am sharing a screenshot of the Windows Server where IIS is:

[image]

If I host the application on a different port (other than 80/443 where SSL is enabled) react app works, as you can see on left hand side image https://localhost:9999. If I host the same application on port  80, it throws all 404/403 errors for the requested files. React application will be hosted as web application under default website.
Please help, how can I resolve 404 issues thrown where app is hosted on SSL enabled port.

Thanks

Comment: Are you tried this? https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied

Comment: Hi Danial, yes. It only solved hosting on non-SSL port and url redirection.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis The issue started to happen when you tried to host the React web app as an application under a site, so clearly you forgot to let that web app know the context. Tons of discussions are already there on such topics, like https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/

Comment: May I know if `atsweb` is an application which you added under the site ?